# Bot Framework C# send parameters in PromptChoice.Choice

Tags: c#, botframework

In my Dialog I am sending a user a prompt dialog:

```
PromptOptions<string> options = new PromptOptions<string>($"some var" + var,
    "invalid",
    "Exceeded",
    context.Activity.ChannelId.ToLower() == "skype" || context.Activity.ChannelId.ToLower() == "webchat" || context.Activity.ChannelId.ToLower() == "emulator" ?
    new List<string>() { "yes","no","exit",  } :
    new List<string>() { "yes", "exit", },
3);
PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, options);
```

and in the method OnOptionSelected:

```
private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    string optionSelected = await result;

    switch (optionSelected)
    {
        case "yes":
            CallMethod(**Param1**, true);
            break;
        case "no":
            CallMethod(**Param1**, false);
            break;
        case "exit":
            context.Call(new ExitDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I pass Param1 to the OnOptionSelected method so I can then use it?

Comment: Param 1 and Param 2 depends on the prompt? or how you will get those?

Comment: Param1 and Param2 will not depend on the promptDialog.

Comment: OK, because you cannot change the signature of the OnOptionSelected method. So basically you will have to go with BotState option

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pass the parameters to the OnOptionSelected method. You cannot change the signature of the `ResumeAfter<T>` method.

The way to go here is probably taking advantage of the BotState to save the values there prior the `PromptDialog` and retrieve them on the `OnOptionSelected` method to use them.

Check the [core-state C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State) sample to know more about how you can use the BotState.

Comment: Was this useful?